# Incorrect email and username in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

here's my issue:

We have a brand new Sharepoint Server that we built out and started adding users by creating a group for them on the server and creating local usernames (so no domain involved) and then adding them to Sharepoint. I added a name wrong. I added server1\bob.shoo when I should have put in server1\bob.shoe.

I tried to delete the local username and build it back brand new, but for some reason when I try to add it back to Sharepoint it still remembers his name and email address as server1\bob.shoo with bob.shoo@email.com.

How can I get Sharepoint to forget all that information? I'm kind of stumped, considering the Sharepoint account was deleted, the incorrect local account was deleted, and this should be brand new. Yet it still sees it as bob.shoo. Is there some way to access the Sharepoint Database to see exactly what's being saved in there and change it? If I could just change it manually I'd be fine with that, but right now it remembers everything incorrectly.

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure by what you mean by "SharePoint Account".

Try deleting the User Profile from under Central Administration > Shared Services Administration > User Profiles and Properties > View User Profiles

Comment: When I mean Sharepoint Account I mean I first add a local user account to the server and then hop into Sharepoint and create a profile for them there. My CA doesn't have that option. Instead I need to go to CA > Security Config > Manage Web Site Users. From there I can enter the web address of the Sharepoint Site and manage members, but the options to manage are very limited. I can basically move them in and out of groups; that's it.

Comment: Yeah. It's seriously confusing. I could understand not being able to change usernames, but I have a hard time believing that I can't change the Display Name, Email Address, and other info.